# Installing rpy2 without admin privileges

Tags: python, r, gcc, rpy2

I am having trouble installing the Python package [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html). I have already compiled R as a shared library, but I do not have admin priviledges so I am trying to install rpy2 with:

```
pip install -user rpy2
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:86:31: fatal error:
>   readline/readline.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I have downloaded `readline` to:

```
/some/path/readline-6.2/
```

where I can see `readline.h` (I have also compiled `readline` just in case)

#### My question:

How can I make `rpy2` (or pip) aware of this location with `readline.h` to avoid the  header compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to actually install readline, not just download it, and then point `rpy2` to it with `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

Try this approach. It's almost working for me - I have the same problem, except an additional wrinkle that rpy2 seems to be linking against the system R instead of my homedir install.

First, I downloaded readline to `~/src/readline-6.2`, and installed it with `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`. (You need to install it somewhere, not just download the source.)

Then I re-compiled R with

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I$HOME/include/" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L$HOME/lib64 -L$HOME/lib" \
./configure --prefix=$HOME --enable-BLAS-shlib --enable-R-shlib
make
make install
```

R is definitely now using that readline:

```
$ ldd ~/lib64/R/lib/libR.so | grep readline
libreadline.so.6 => /home/dsutherl/lib/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f8104207000)
```

The same for my in-home install of Python (3.2.3, since h5py doesn't work with 3.3 yet):

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I$HOME/include/" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L$HOME/lib64 -L$HOME/lib" \
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

And again:

```
$ ldd ~/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-32m.so | grep readline
libreadline.so.6 => /home/dsutherl/lib/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fbfff5c2000)
```

Then I downloaded the rpy2 source and built that:

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I$HOME/include/" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L$HOME/lib64 -L$HOME/lib" \
python3 setup.py build --r-home $HOME/lib64/R install
```

This seemed successful, and `ldd`ing the `.so`s in `site-packages/rpy2` links to the right `libreadline`...but to the system `R`, instead of mine, despite the explicit `--r-home`.

Comment: Thanks Dougal. I followed these steps but somehow I am still suffering from the problem  `/path/to/python2.7/site-
packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so: undefined symbol: Rf_translateCharUTF8` By the way, I think that your error is possibly due to the fact that Rpy2 looks up R from `$PATH`, and it tries to infer the R home directory from it. If you update `$PATH` to make sure it sees `$HOME/bin/` before the system PATH you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

more simple :

```
yum install readline-devel.x86_64
```

run for me on centos 7

for debian/ubuntu

```
apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

Comment: Don't both of these require root?

Answer (score -2):

Sometime in linux is needed an sudo apt-get upgrade, to get the news libraries, may work

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid I do not have the privileges to do this. Is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score -2):

This is another option, but too you need root privilegies ...
     sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev

Comment: While you're there: `sudo apt-get install python-rpy2`. But as OP said: no admin...