# rpy2 complaining with undefined symbol: Rf_translateCharUTF8

Tags: python, r, readline, rpy2

I built R and rpy2 following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824147/283296), and when I test `import rpy2.tests` I get the following error:

`/path/to/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so: undefined symbol: Rf_translateCharUTF8`

in an exception thrown by `rpy2.interface._rinterface import *`

Any thoughts why?

Comment: After so many problems trying to get rpy2 to work for ages, I have instead began using PypeR, which was quite straight forward to get it running (and works on windows 7 64 bit).

Comment: Lucas I believe that this comment is not really useful I don't think it can help the OP to resolve his problem. Besides that @lgautier, the creator of rpy2, is an active SO user and generally( and I am pretty sure) he come here with an answer.

Comment: @Lucas: I have been repeating that there is no real support for MS Windows because of lack of contributions to get it to work there, at few notable exceptions (you know who you are - thanks for your work). Thanks to Christoph Gohlke here is also an unofficial repository of compiled binaries: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2

Comment: Sorry, did not mean in any way to disparage the huge contribution that rpy2 has been to the r community. Thanks for the link, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether a similar report on the [rpy-list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.rpy/3430) helped ?

I am seeing only now that the person who asked the question did not report that the problem was solved, but I think that the problem was with the system picking the wrong libR.so.

If using Linux, you could also consider using ready-made packages for R and rpy2 (on debian-based distribution, I know that there are repositories with always-up-to-date versions).

Comment: Thanks, but I read that exact thread on the rpy-list before posting and followed the same steps, and I am certainly still having the problem that you mention. By the way, those steps are essentially the same ones discussed in the answer that I link to in my OP (i.e. basically build from source with `python setup build --r-home <path_to_desired_R> install` and use `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS` AND `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point  to the right `readline` library, and predefine the env variables `RHOME`, `R_HOME` to point to the root directory of the R installation)

Comment: `python -m rpy2.tests` should spit out on the console the R version rpy2 was built against. Does it match what you are expecting ? (note: I have not used the `--r-home` option in a long time, it might good to check that it does what it is supposed to).

Comment: What I testing/working with regularly is: 1) have the right R found first in the $PATH, 2) set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to have the directory that contains libR.so for the R in the $PATH. unset RHOME or R_HOME.